# How to write a method that increments a file name in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a method that takes a a string of html and writes it to a file. The method should increment the file name if the file already exists. For example, if `wordmatch.html` already exists then a new file should be created `wordmatch1.html` so and so fourth.

I have created a method that writes the html to a file. I'm working on the last part to incrementally change the name of a new file if the file already exists.

```
public void saveContent(WordMatch wordMatch){
    logger.info(wordMatch);
    try {
    File file = new File("wordmatch0.html");
    String html = wordMatch.toString();
    String cleanedHTML = html.replace("WordMatch(content=","").replace(")","");
    logger.info(cleanedHTML);
    if (file.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("File created: " + file.getName());
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("word_match.html");
            myWriter.write(cleanedHTML);
            myWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        String fileName = file.getName().toString();
        String index = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("h") + 1);
        index = index.substring(0, index.indexOf("."));
        Integer parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(index);
        System.out.println(parsedInt);
        parsedInt+=1;
        fileName = fileName.replace(index,parsedInt.toString());
        System.out.println(fileName);
        System.out.println("fileName should have been printed by now");
        file = new File(fileName);
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        myWriter.write(cleanedHTML);
        myWriter.close();
        //TODO add method to write file name with new index
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: You can have a look over here [Java Docs for FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) it's of form `listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)` and for naming the file you can use `for loop` to increment number if filename is already present

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach will be count the number of files matching your file name and then increment the `numberOfFiles` to create a new file name :

```
Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("C:\\your\\local\\path"));
long numberOfFiles = files.map(Path.class::cast)
                          .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("wordmatch"))
                          .count();
```

After all you have to manage certains situations, to have a good algorithm for managing your files.

Comment: Where are you getting Files from?

Comment: @harry - a good simple solution.  Personally I prefer just to add the millis on to the end, so that sorting is always good.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, yes it is also a kind of pattern that can be used for file naming

Answer (score 0):

A problem that seems trivial but has so many pitfalls.

The algorithm you wrote won't work for the following reasons:

1. Simple if-else is not enough, you need to go through a loop to find the last index, because potentially there could be many files created already.
2. Else block tries to find an index from the file name that should't have one.

Moreover, there are additional questions that may raise.

- What if someone deleted the intermediate indexes and now you have 1 and 4, do you want to go with 2 or 5?
- Can someone delete the files from the directory except the programm?
- Are nested directories possible?
- How often files are created?
- Can someone manually create a file with a proper name bypassing the programm?

And more importand question is - do you really want to stick to the strict brute-force counter on the actual files listed in a directory?

If the answer is yes, the more reasonable would be to check the files using [File.list()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()), sort them, take the last index and increment them instead of trying to create a file and increment on a failure.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File directoryPath = new File("path_to_your_dir");

        FilenameFilter filenameFilter = (dir, name) -> !dir.isFile();
        Integer maxIndex = Arrays.stream(directoryPath.list(filenameFilter))
                // Take numeric index from the end of the file name, beware of file extensions!
                .map(name -> name.substring("word_match".length(), name.lastIndexOf('.')))
                .map(Main::parseOrDefault) // Parse it to a number
                .max(Integer::compareTo) // Define how to compare them
                .orElse(-1);
        // -1 is no files, 0 if a file with no index, otherwise max index
        System.out.println(maxIndex);
    }

    private static Integer parseOrDefault(String integer) {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(integer);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If the answer is no, you can have a counter that is persisted somewhere (file system, BD) and incremented regardless every time.
And more simple approach is establish a frequence of file creations and simply append a timestamp/date-time to the end of each file.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. I've updated the question. You are right this algorithm will require some type of looping.